# Order xml superclass elements in Java serialization

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have two classes ParentClass and ChildClass in JAVA using JAXB.
ChildClass extends ParentClass.
When I serialize an object of ChildClass, in the resulting XML, ParentClass properties appear first, I would like to have ChildClass properties first and then ParentClass properties.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason JAXB does this is to match inheritance in XML schema.  However, you could do something like the following:

- Mark the parent @XmlTransient
- Set the propOrder on the child class

**Parent**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlTransient
public abstract class Parent {

    private String parentProp;

    public String getParentProp() {
        return parentProp;
    }

    public void setParentProp(String parentProp) {
        this.parentProp = parentProp;
    }

}
```

**Child**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"childProp", "parentProp"})
public class Child extends Parent {

    private String childProp;

    public String getChildProp() {
        return childProp;
    }

    public void setChildProp(String childProp) {
        this.childProp = childProp;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Child.class);

        Child child = new Child();
        child.setParentProp("parent-value");
        child.setChildProp("child-value");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(child, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<child>
    <childProp>child-value</childProp>
    <parentProp>parent-value</parentProp>
</child>
```

Comment: cool answer,1. does this work with schema validation (when unmarshalling) ? 2. will it work with @XmlTransient but without proporder

Comment: @ekeren - 1.  Depends on what the XML schema looks like, if there is inheritance between the complex types then it is expected that the parent types properties occur before the child types properties.  2.  Yes, but without propOrder the order is dependent upon the JAXB impl.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan is there another way to have child properties first without hartcoding parent properties? having annotations like these child annotation, it violates a bit the OOP paradigm... I'm using EclipseLink MOXy

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Hi, is it possible to redefine order of properties in a superclass? For example, I have a model object "BaseClass" that is concrete with it's own ordering. The subclass "SubClass" that extends this object wants to reorder the properties in the baseclass(Because we have a catch all 'XmlAny' as the last property in the BaseClass and this would interfere with the sub class's properties). Is it possible without using XmlTransient on the BaseClass?